# Editable blocks on page (not related to model - related to SEO) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My SEO-people do not write code. All they love is creating good texts. All they can do is pasting texts do database via some nice forms.

The problem is that sometimes they ask me: we need to put *the text* into page footer. Wee need to put *some other text* into page header.

And I just can not edit the code every time SEO-man asks me!

And sometimes the text are not related directly to model. I think you will understand me that it is a bad idea to create `footer_block` field inside a `Car` or `Person` model.

How nice it would if there was a gem that could:

1. Load text data from database by key (for example 'FOOTER_BLOCK'). To let me not to turn the models into a mess!
2. Give us forms where a SEO-person could paste the text
3. (Would be nice) Give us a WISIWIG editor.

PS: An example of such functionality (but not in Ruby): I used to code in python/Django. And we used `django-flatblocks` package - it did fit these 3 criterias.

Comment: Writing an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any gem which will do this, but hopefully I can shed some light on how you might be able to achieve it

---

**Code Blocks**

You could create a table (and model) called `code_blocks`. The schema may look like this:

```
code_blocks
id | title | body | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to create any number of records in this table that you want, and then call them from your app without the need for specific controller actions

---

**Display**

You could do this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def code_block(id)
    block = CodeBlock.find(id)
    return block.body
end
```

This may be inefficient, but it will allow you to include the code blocks whereever you want on the page, independent of the controller actions

So, for example, you have a footer block with id as 3, you could put:

```
<%= code_block(3) %>
```

---

**Editing**

This will mean that if you have a simple backend form, you can set it up so that you list the blocks by title, and allow the SEO guys to edit the HTML with a WYSIWYG editor (saving the HTML in the `body` column)

Comment: Thanks! But I still wish if there was a gem that helped me to avoid coding (even simple backends). Hey, I could use ActiveAdmin or something! :)